# Result is always Not a Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, parseint

I have a problem with the code below. When I give the code suitable interger and string values, the result is always not a number. I tried to multiplicate the integers with *1 and I also tried to parse the integer var to int but nothing is working.

```
module.exports = async function CalculateUV(context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

   
    const stringA = (req.query.stringA || (req.body && req.body.stringA));
    const stringB = (req.query.stringB || (req.body && req.body.stringB));
    const stringC = (req.query.stringC || (req.body && req.body.stringC));

    var integerA = (req.query.integerA || (req.body && req.body.integerA));
    var integerB = (req.query.integerB || (req.body && req.body.integerB));
    var integerC = (req.query.integerC || (req.body && req.body.integerC));
    var integerD = (req.query.integerD || (req.body && req.body.integerD));
  
    

    var result;

    if (stringA == 'hello' && stringB == 'world') {

       switch (stringC) {
                case 'one':
                    result = 0;
                    break;
                case 'two':
                    result = (integerA + integerB) * (+integerD / 100);
                    break;
                case 'three':
                    result = (integerA + integerB) * (intergerD / 100);
                    break;
                case 'four':
                    result = (integerC) * (integerD / 100);
                    break;
                default:
                    result = 0;
            }
    }
    else {
        result = 'Error';
    }
    
     context.res = {
       // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: 'The result value is:' + result
     };
}
```

Comment: Please share values of `stringA`, `stringB`, `stringC` and `integerA`, `integerB`, `integerC`, `integerD` - console.log will be the best to get those values

Comment: The values do not really matter, they are just natural positv numbers and short strings.

For Instance:
IntegerA = 100
IntegerB = 1000
IntegerC = 50
IntegerD = 40
StringA = hello
StringB = world
StringC = one, two, three or four

Comment: request.query values are always stirngs. You need to use it like this: `parseInt(req.query.integerA)` etc

Comment: Already tried parseInt, it is not working.

Comment: Where did you try it?

Comment: Some screenshot with `console.log(req.query)` and `console.log(req.body)` will be helpful

Comment: First try:
 var integerA = (req.query.integerA || (req.body && req.body.integerA));
parseInt(integerA)
-------------------------------------
Second try:
 var paseInt(integerA) = (req.query.integerA || (req.body && req.body.integerA));
-----------------------------
Third try:
 var integerA = (paseInt(req.query.integerA) || (req.body && req.body.integerA));

all of that was not working

Comment: The values do matter, `result` can only be `NaN` if `stringA` is `"hello"`, `stringB` is  `"world"` and `stringC` is either `"two"`, `"three"` or `"four"`. This would mean that one of your integer variables is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

result = (+integerA + +integerB) *(integerD / 100);
break;

Or,

result =
You need to be careful while using numerical strings during addition. Req.query is a string, even if you have put a number value in a query.
That's probably why you're getting a NaN, because you were multiplying a string with a number.

Other operators(* ,/ ,-), don't do this. Hence no need to do this for them.

Answer (score 0):

req.query.x is always a string (since it is exported from the url). You need to parse it as an Int:

```js
function CalculateUV (req) {
    const stringA = (req.query.stringA || (req.body && req.body.stringA));
    const stringB = (req.query.stringB || (req.body && req.body.stringB));
    const stringC = (req.query.stringC || (req.body && req.body.stringC));

    var integerA = (parseInt(req.query.integerA, 10) || (req.body && req.body.integerA));
    var integerB = (parseInt(req.query.integerB, 10) || (req.body && req.body.integerB));
    var integerC = (parseInt(req.query.integerC, 10) || (req.body && req.body.integerC));
    var integerD = (parseInt(req.query.integerD, 10) || (req.body && req.body.integerD));
  
    

    var result;

    if (stringA == 'hello' && stringB == 'world') {

      switch (stringC) {
        case 'one':
            result = 0;
            break;
        case 'two':
            result = (integerA + integerB) * (+integerD / 100);
            break;
        case 'three':
            result = (integerA + integerB) * (integerD / 100);
            break;
        case 'four':
            result = (integerC) * (integerD / 100);
            break;
        default:
            result = 0;
      }
    } else {
      result = 'Error';
    }
    const res = {
      body: 'The result value is:' + result
    };
    console.log(res);
}


const req = {
  query: {
    stringA: 'hello',
    stringB: 'world',
    stringC: 'three',
    integerA: '1',
    integerB: '2',
    integerC: '3',
    integerD: '4',
  },
  body: {
      stringA: 'four',
      stringB: 'five',
      stringC: 'six',
      integerA: 5,
      integerB: 6,
      integerC: 7,
      integerD: 8,
  },

}
CalculateUV(req);
```

Note that if the parseInt(req.query.integerX, 10) returns `0` it will count as false and the var integerX will calculate the second part of the expression (after the `||`)

PS: You had a typo in `case 'three'`, `intergerD` should be `integerD`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var integerA = (req.query.integerA || (req.body && req.body.integerA));
var integerB = (req.query.integerB || (req.body && req.body.integerB));
var integerC = (req.query.integerC || (req.body && req.body.integerC));
var integerD = (req.query.integerD || (req.body && req.body.integerD));
```

replace the above lines with the bellow one

```
     var integerA = parseInt(req.query.integerA || (req.body && req.body.integerA));
var integerB = parseInt(req.query.integerB || (req.body && req.body.integerB));
var integerC = parseInt(req.query.integerC || (req.body && req.body.integerC));
var integerD = parseInt(req.query.integerD || (req.body && req.body.integerD));
```

Also remove the + prior to integerD like bellow one

```
result = (integerA + integerB) * (integerD / 100);
```

It should work now